# Maven Dependency for com.day.util

Tags: java, maven, aem

I have been using Adobe CQ5.5 and need to use a class in com.day.util .
I am not getting any maven dependency for this util . And as a result , class using this package fails to compile .

After exhausted googling , I am posting this question..Has anybody used this package before and got similar kind of issues ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I use http://mvnrepository.com but it has no suggestions either.

Comment: How about Adobe Maven Repository? http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/Development/maven/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html

Comment: Hi Peter and gTito , after spending some good amount of tome in it, I found the dependency for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the dependency for com.day.util

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>day-commons-misc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This artifact is not part of the standard Maven repository.

A quick google search reveals that it is found in Adobe's Maven repository.

You will have to modify your project's pom.xml to include Adobe's Maven repository under section < repositories >.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jarvana.com](http://jarvana.com) for this purpose and I find it very useful.